# How do I set an array in one class with another array in another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, nsarray

I've populated and array with data like this in one class...

```
PowerClass.h 

NSMutableArray pickerArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray pickerArray;
```

-

```
PowerClass.m

@synthesize pickerArray;

@implementation
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"stef", @"steve", @"baddamans", @"jonny", nil];
pickerArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
```

And I'm trying to set the Array in another class

```
WeekClass.h

PowerClass          *powerClass;
NSMutableArray  *pickerData;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray pickerData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) PowerClass *powerClass;

WeekClass.m

@implementation
pickerData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:powerClass.pickerArray];
```

I have no errors or warnings.  It just crashes.  The NSLog says that the powerClass.pickerArray is NULL.

Please help point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Memory management!

You've set `pickerArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];`, which is an autoreleased object. By the time you ask for pickerArray later, it's disappeared!

The solution is to use the `@synthesize`d accessors. Instead of:

```
pickerArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
```

... use one of the following:

```
[self setPickerArray:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array]];
self.pickerArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
//These two are exactly equivalent, but are both very different from what you have now.
```

This way, your property will handle memory management for you.

Comment: Hi, Cheers I put my question wrong... Sorry... I meant Week Class picker.Data was null...  What can I do?

(Sorry, It was 4am UK when I sent it :-) )

Thanx again...